# Shall I mount /boot partition and if yes, can I make it read-only

Tags: linux, boot, mount

I've got a separate /boot partition on an SSD drive. Do I have to mount it at all and if yes, can I make it read-only?
Current fstab:

```
    UUID=783b2uhe7-2a2780abfxd0 /boot                ext4       acl,user_xattr,noatime       1 2
```

If I just delete/comment out this line in fstab, will it affect OS functioning and will it lead to /boot partition not being mounted? Or it is mounted during boot process irrespective of fstab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it will not break your operating system in the current state, an update (especially to kernel and kernel-mods) to your system might need to adjust the boot loader, breaking your system (and causing a time-consuming recovery).

If you comment it out, it will not be mounted on boot. You could mount it read-only, but I don't see any advantage in that: it will not allow changes during an update to be correctly applied.